# How can I avoid linking directly to library files in cmake?

Tags: c++, cmake

I'm writing a c project using cmake on a mac. I use homebrew. I installed libpqxx via homebrew. I have the following CMakeLists.txt.

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.11)
project(imagedb)

set(CMAKE_CXX_STANDARD 14)
add_executable(imagedb main.cpp)

target_link_libraries( imagedb /usr/local/lib/libpqxx.dylib)
```

While this builds I would like to avoid using an absolute path here. How can I do this using cmake given that `/usr/local` is already in the path prefix?

Answer (score 1):

Usually you should use `find_package` to find dependencies.

Looking at [libpqxx](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/tree/master/cmake)'s repo, you can see that they provide a CMake config file.

So in your `CMakeLists.txt` file you just have to do this:

```
find_package(libpqxx REQUIRED)
target_link_libraries(imagedb libpqxx::pqxx_shared)
```

If for some reason `libpqxx-config.cmake` is not shipped with the homebrew version, you have to write a [find file](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries#writing-find-modules).

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can you expand your answer on how you got "libpqxx::pqxx_shared" from looking at the repo? Also its not working so I'm assuming that homebrew does not provide the cmake file.

Comment: I was just pointing to the `libpqxx-config.cmake`, which does not necessarily list the targets. The targets of a package are defined usually defined in  `CMakeLists.txt` files and exported to a `libpqxx-targets.cmake` file. Looking at the `CMakeLists.txt` in the `src` directory, you can see that in line [78](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L78) they add a library named `pqxxs_hared` which then gets exported as a target `libpqxx::pqxx_shared` in the macro [here](https://github.com/jtv/libpqxx/blob/master/src/CMakeLists.txt#L35).

Comment: In that case, you should write a `Findlibpqxx.cmake` file as describe [here](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/community/wikis/doc/tutorials/How-To-Find-Libraries#writing-find-modules).